# HTML designMode, move cursor programmatically using default keypress handlers

Tags: javascript, designmode

**Although I already got an answer, I'll start a small bounty on this one. As the answer is that it is impossible, I'm searching for an alternative solution or some other suggestion.**

I'm making a very customized editor using the HTML designMode. In one situation, I want the default action of a keypress be accomplished twice when pressing the actual key once. In this case, I am talking about the DOWN key (keyCode 40). When pressing that, I want to skip one line, putting the cursor (`|`) on the next. Like:

```
First li|ne
Second line
The third line
```

After pressing the down arrow key:

```
First line
Second line
The third| line
```

I have tried setting up keypress events programmatically, having them trigged by JavaScript, but that does not happen to move the cursor. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: I predict you won't get an answer you'll like, even with the bounty :)

Comment: I'm afraid so. Then you'll have additional 50. :)

Comment: If you're working with monospace text, take a look at http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/KeyTable. It might work nicely for you if you can hack it a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to do this in a sensible way. The only way to move the caret programmatically in non-IE browsers is by using the browser's `Selection` object, which has no mechanism for emulating a down arrow keypress.

Comment: Okay. I can add an event listener waiting for the down arrow keypress, then move the cursor via the Selection object, then preventDefault(). I'm quite fine with that. However, after setting the new cursor position, it takes a while before it updates. I don't know why, but first it looks like it disappears, then after half a second or so, it updates. It feels like there is something that the default handler does to finish the movement that I prevent it from doing.

Comment: What method of the Selection object are you using to move the caret? I assumed you wanted the precise placement of the caret directly underneath its previous position that down arrow gives you.

Comment: I find that things usually work better in an event handler if preventDefault() is the first thing I do - maybe try that?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a combination of a few techniques.  The first would be a function to move the cursor to an arbitrary position in a text area:

```
function setCaretPosition(elemId, caretPos) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(elemId);

    if(elem != null) {
        if(elem.createTextRange) {
            var range = elem.createTextRange();
            range.move('character', caretPos);
            range.select();
        }
        else {
            if(elem.selectionStart) {
                elem.focus();
                elem.setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPos);
            }
            else
                elem.focus();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is from this [blog post](http://blog.josh420.com/.../setting-cursor-position-in-a-textbox-or-textarea-with-javascript.aspx), which I had to use the google cache to view.  Next you'd need to find the [current cursor position in the textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-textarea).

Finally, using the current cursor position, you could get the indexOf() the carriage returns in relation to your cursor position and use that to move your cursor down 2 lines.

Pretty it ain't, but it should work.

Comment: The question isn't about text in a textarea, it's about HTML in an editable document.

Comment: Thanks, but as Tim says, it does not work in an editable HTML document.